# More Importantly or More Important, Modifying?

Tags: grammar, adverbial-phrases

> What we see may mean something. And, more importantly, how we see things may mean something.

Does *more importantly* seem grammatically proper? Or, do you use *more important*?

I may not get what, *more importantly*, and, or, *importantly* may modify, here. I think an adverb, and, or, adverbial phrase modifies a verb, so, it may modify *see*? Or, may you use *more important*, and, or, *important*, as an adjectival phrase, to modify a sentence that comes after it?

Comment: "More importantly" is the correct one. The same with "less/equally/most importantly".

Comment: Please don't write incorrect answers as comments.  Comments can't be downvoted.

Comment: I think I read this, [here](https://www.grammarbook.com/homonyms/more-importantly-most-importantly.asp). What may I think of this?

Comment: How is it an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 1):

If *more important* was an adjective phrase modifying the entire subsequent phrase *how we see things may mean something* then you'd need an additional verb otherwise the sentence would be incomplete.  Because that phrase would then be a "noun", but there would be no outside verb.

So you'd need to do something like this.

> [*It's*] More important that how we see things may mean something

Since this is not happening, *more importantly* needs to be an adverb modifying *mean*.